# Tool/Software to Bookmark Positions in Audio

Tags: audio

I'm listening to many different, and quite lengthy, audios (lectures spanning 4-5 hours) and am not able to finish them in a single sitting.

So I'm looking for a tool that lets me bookmark positions in the audio and possibly let me take notes. So for instance at 02:15:47 position in the audio, I would like to bookmark it, write some notes (i.e. which topic is now being discussed etc) and then save it. So later on if I need to lookup things I can do so quickly.

Is there any such tool available? Be it Windows or Linux?

Comment: Might be worth looking into audio books readers, some of them offer this kind of functionality. It also seems that banshee http://banshee.fm/about/features/ has this feature.

Comment: I cover this in my answer here : http://sound.stackexchange.com/a/40193/16723 for audacity(freeware)

Comment: What platform are you looking for to use this software on - desktop or mobile? I might assume that if you are listening to material of substantial length, you would be listening to it on a tablet or a mobile device. Can you clarify?

Comment: Additional use case: Language learning (marking and returning to languages), annotated note taking.

Answer (score 1):

Many softwares allows you to put comments on markers, you can also find in some of them auto-marking functions (see Sound Forge).

Here is a non-exhaustive list of them with a related "How-To" article:

- [Sony - Sound Forge](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/fr/soundforgepro)

  - [interesting article](https://www.custcenter.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/155/~/how-do-i%3A-automatically-create-regions-using-the-auto-region-tool)
- [Avid - Pro Tools](http://www.avid.com/EN/products/family/Pro-Tools)

  - [interesting article](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Marker-in-Pro-Tools)
- [Ableton - Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/)

  - [interesting article](https://www.ableton.com/answers/right-ctrl-click-to-add-post-it-style-notes-arrangement-view-on-beat-time-ruler-eom)

Comment: If you have Pro Tools, either use markers or clip groups, so you can put the notes in the file names and then color code them and places them on different tracks for different categories.

Answer (score 1):

Reaper would be a good solution as it allows you to use markers but also regions (that you can create from a time selection for instance). It also has a very convenient and dockable region/marker manager with a search engine. A click on a region or marker and you get at the right timing. Of course, you can also put the color you want on every marker.

You can try it for free, even if it's not exactly a freeware: http://reaper.fm/